# Titanium for Android: processing SEND intent keeps timing out

Tags: android, android-intent, titanium

I'm new to android development -- working on my first app for Android, using Titanium.

I'm running into a problem where my app keeps timing out, but I can't figure out why.  I have a feeling there is just something fundamentally wrong in my approach / understanding of how Titanium & android work, but I haven't been able to figure it out yet.

My app is essentially a bookmarking tool, similar to delicious for android.  It:

- Hooks into the SEND intent, to capture sharing intents from other apps
- Takes the subject and text from the SEND intent, and does some processing to parse out a URL and title
- passes those data to a web page

The code is as follows:

in `/platform/android/AndroidManifest.xml`, I add an intent filter to capture the SEND action:

```
<activity android:name=".Advocateio2Activity"
    android:label="Advocate.io"
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
```

and in `/Resources/app.js`, I check for the send intent, process, and open a special URL:

```
(function() {
    var baseUrl = "http://mydomain.com/bookmarklet";
    var intent = Ti.Android.currentActivity.getIntent();

    var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
        backgroundColor: '#000',
        fullscreen: false,
        exitOnClose: true,
        layout: "vertical"
    });

    if (intent.hasExtra(Ti.Android.EXTRA_TEXT)) {
        win.open();
        var title = intent.getStringExtra(Ti.Android.EXTRA_SUBJECT);
        var body = intent.getStringExtra(Ti.Android.EXTRA_TEXT).replace(/\n/g, " ");
        var parts = body.split(" ");

        for (var i=0; i<parts.length; i++) {
            if (parts[i].search(/htt*/) == 0) {
                // this is a URL
                var url = parts[i];
                var bookmarklet_url = baseUrl + '?url=' + encodeURIComponent(url) + '&title=' + encodeURIComponent(title) + '&mobile=1';
            }
        }
        if (bookmarklet_url) {
            Ti.Platform.openURL(bookmarklet_url);   
        }
        win.close();
    }   

})();
```

That's basically the whole app.  Very simple idea.

When I debug and install directly (via Titanium Studio) it works fine, but when I publish to the Play Store, the app crashes every time.

The app hangs when processing the SEND intent (after I've chosen my app from the "share" menu) -- just delivering a black screen.  If I run a debug session, I see that there's an `Activity idle timeout for ActivityRecord` happening, but I'm not sure why.

My guess is that I just don't get something about how the flow works in android apps, and that I'm leaking memory, spawning an infinite loop, or not managing my application views/windows correctly.

In any case, I'm completely stuck -- have been debugging this for over a week now and I can't get consistent results.

Any help would be **majorly** appreciated.

Thanks!!

Comment: is it possible that your app is looking for the `MAIN` intent and not finding it? Something like this maybe https://github.com/emmett9001/parsely-android/blob/master/HiParsely/AndroidManifest.xml#L24

Comment: Unfortunately that did not do the trick, but thanks for the help!